# Setup a unix-based MySQL database for remote access

Tags: mysql, database

I am new to SQL in general, and am having trouble configuring my server.

**Background**: I have a MySQL server running on unix. I formatted a database using `-h localhost` as my dbhost-type. I am now querying the database, and it works great locally, but I need to be able to query the database from a different machine.

Can someone please tell me what needs to happen to get an IP address for my SQL server, so that I may connect to it remotely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your configuration file. I.e.: **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**

Find the bind-address entry:

```
bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
```

and comment it out, by adding a hash in front of it:

```
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
```

Restart MySQL and you are ready.